# Solve for $y$ in the given equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve:
$$y^{y\sqrt {y}}=(y\sqrt {y})^{y}$$

My Attempt:
$$y^{y\sqrt {y}}=(y\sqrt {y})^{y}$$
$$y^{y^{\dfrac {3}{2}}}=(y^{\dfrac {3}{2}})^y$$

How do I solve further?

Comment: Take logarithms.

Answer (score 1):

The domain is $y>0$.

We need to solve 
$$y^{y\sqrt{y}}=y^{\frac{3}{2}y},$$
which gives $y=1$ or
$$y\sqrt{y}=\frac{3}{2}y,$$
which is $y=\frac{9}{4}$ and we get the answer: $\{1,\frac{9}{4}\}$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate which method did you use?

Comment: @blue_eyed_ Since $(a^x)^y=a^{xy}$, we obtain: $\left(y^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)^y=y^{\frac{3}{2}y}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use logarithm?

y = 1 is a solution.

Let $y \not = 1$.

\[
y^{3/2}\log y = 3y/2 \log y 
\]
or dividing by $y \log y$,
\[
y^{1/2} = 3/2.
\]

Answer (score -1):

$y^{y^3\over 2}={y^y} {y^{y\over 2}}$

$y^{y^3\over 2}={y^3y\over 2}$

$\frac{y^3} 2 =\frac {3y} 2 $

$2{y^3\over 2}=3y$

$4{y^3}=9y^2$

$4{y^3}-9{y^2}=0$

${y^2}(4y-9)=0$

$SS={\{0,0,{9\over 4}}\}$

However if you define $0^0$ as an indeterminate form the only root to this equation is $9\over 4$.